# CSS: stretch content to sticky footer

Tags: css

I want to stretch the navigation and content column to the bottom of the .page_wrapper

See:
http://jsfiddle.net/KqQ42/8/

I already tried following:

```
min-height: 100%;
height: auto;
```

But this doesn't change anything....

What else do I need to add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrating **[faux columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/)** does the trick.

This way, you're simulating a 100% height navigation and content via a background image.

**Live Demo**: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TqKMW/)

Comment: Hi, is there really no way doing this with css (don't having to use percentages)?

Comment: I think it's only possible with positioning the navigation and content absolute. **Or** here another possibility: http://jsfiddle.net/3ETm9/1/ as you can see, `#navigation` is 100% height and inside, there's an list-navigation with a margin top. This may fix your problem, otherwise, I don't see another way doing this. Hope this helps.

Comment: Faux columns has to be the most ugly possible fix for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you want flexible height based on the size of the window you can use percentages for your heights. In this case you need to use percentages on all the containers/divs.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/KqQ42/11/